# Adapter response body has /*-secure- ... */

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm receiving this response from a mobilefirst adapter. The callback function just returns the object sans the `/*-secure- ... */`. Where does it come from?

```
/*-secure-
{"isSuccessful":true,"result":"No subscription found for user."}*/
```

Comment: That is not stopping you from parsing anything. Provide the code you have implemented where you attempt to parse it...

Comment: Hi @IdanAdar. No it doesn't. I just want to understand where it comes from. Will edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of the response generated by the MobileFirst Server, it holds no meaning to the response object itself and will not prevent any operations to be done on said object.